# Magento creates new eav attribute values instead of updating existing ones

Tags: magento-1.9, eav-attributes, magento-1.9.1.1

I am facing a bad maintained Magento 1.9.1.1 installation and saw in the  `catalog_category_entity_text` table many duplicate entries. The duplicates have the same `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, and `store_id` but different values.

This affects multiple attributes, entities (categories) and stores. It looks like the following:
[image: duplicate entries]

My presumption is that Magento instead of overwriting the current value just saves a new entry. E.g. I have a category with the description "description 1" and now I change it to "description 2" then I will find both values in the table.

I don't think this is actually Magento default behavior but rather caused by any third party extension or am I wrong?

If this is not default behavior did anyone see something like this before and has a way of debugging this issue?

Comment: I really don't think this is normal Magento 1 behavior. But maybe some kind of hacky versioning plugin? Or just a bug.